# Selenium TestNG - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: selenium, test-ng

he estado intentando hacer una prueba con testng en selenium, pero me está arrojando la siguiente excepción al ejecutar:

```
FAILED: Login
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Vejez.prueba1Vejez.Login(prueba1Vejez.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

mi código es el siguiente:

```
package Vejez;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class prueba1Vejez {

public String baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/";
String driverPath = "C:\\chromedriver.exe";
public WebDriver driver ;

@BeforeTest
public void launchBroser() {
    System.out.println("launching chrome browser"); 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");            
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get(baseUrl);

}

@Test (priority = 0)
public void Login() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("prueba@gmail.com");
}

/*
@AfterTest
public void CloseExplorer() {
    driver.close();
} */



}
```

alguien tendría una idea de cual puede ser el error? de antemano gracias.

Comment: la línea 30 cuál es?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("prueba@gmail.com");

Comment: divìdelo en dos lìneas, yo creo que en tu página no halla el id ´identifierId´ y por ello al regresar nulo se convierte en null.sendKeys("bla bla bla") lo que es un NPE

Comment: Disculpa, no entendí lo de dividirlo en dos líneas, me podrías explicar? aunque hice la prueba sin aplicar TestNG y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Ya encontré el error, estaba declarando en el launchBrowser  nuevamente el WebDriver driver por lo cual no lo ejecutaba correctamente en el login, lo único que hice fue usar el driver que ya había declarado al inicio.